# How do you write a vector with an underline instead of an arrow?

Tags: math-mode, vector

I don't like the way the vector with an arrow `$\vec{x}$` looks. I would prefer to indicate it with a line underline but when I google it nothing comes up to show me how to do it. Does anyone know?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}


\begin{document}

 \vec{x} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: I did but someone edited it out.

Comment: the macro itself is not an MWE. It is customary here to include the simplest document starting from `\documentclass{...} ... \end{document}` such that users can copy/paste your code and work on it directly.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Here is a comparison of a few techniques to represent a vector (not sure about the `\overline`, `\underline` ones as I don't think that that is standard usage):

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 


\begin{document}
$\vec{x}$  $\overline{x}$  $\underline{x}$  $\mathbf{x}$

$\vec{\mathbf{x}}$  $\overline{\mathbf{x}}$  $\underline{\mathbf{x}}$ 
\end{document}
```

Comment: I really dislike using `\mathbf` since the font changes to upright. I want my vectors italic according to ISO 80000-2. Previously I have used the Boldmath `bm` package, now I use `isomath` for this.

Comment: @MartinUeding: I am not familiar with isomath. Perhaps you should post an answer.

Comment: Can you underline a single blank space in an align (math mode)?

Comment: @Jeff: Should be able to. Try using `\underline{\phantom{\space}}`.  Otherwise, I'd suggest posting a new question.

Answer (score 38):

You can renew the command `\vec`.

```
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\underline{#1}}
```

In this case, if you use `\vec` your vector will be underlined. If you change mind and you want to use a dot or whatever, you can change the definition and all your `\vec` on the document will automatically change in the next compilation.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\underline{#1}}

\begin{document}
\[
   \vec{x} = \cdots % "x" will be underlined
\]
\end{document}
```