# How do I underline capital letters in math-mode

Tags: math-mode, underline

I want `Z` underlined to show it as a complex number in math-mode. For lowercase `z` I can use `\underline{z}` but if I use it with `Z` it displays the normal Letter without a underline.
How do I get a underline below my `Z`?

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. community. What is your minimal complete code in tex format?

Comment: `\underline{Z}` works in a minimal article class document. (although arguably it extends too far to the right and would be prettier if extending only about to the length of the bottom horizontal part of that letter)

Answer (score 4):

According to this [related post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75745/how-do-you-write-a-vector-with-an-underline-instead-of-an-arrow): what you are missing is `\usepackage{amsmath}` then `$\underline{X}$` should do the trick, see minimal example:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath} 
    
    
\begin{document}
    $\vec{x}$  $\overline{x}$  $\underline{x}$  $\mathbf{x}$
    
    $\vec{\mathbf{x}}$  $\overline{\mathbf{x}}$  $\underline{\mathbf{x}}$ 
   
    $\underline{X}$ 
    
\end{document}
```

works, also with capital letters. [image]

Comment: I compiled your document commenting out loading of amsmath and output is very comparable.  In particular for `\underline{X}`.